# How to access weight variables in Keras layers in tensor form for clip_by_weight?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm implementing WGAN and need to clip weight variables.

I'm currently using *Tensorflow* with *Keras* as high-level API. Thus building layers with Keras to avoid manually creation and initialization of variables.

The problem is WGAN need to clip weight varibales, This can be done using `tf.clip_by_value(x, v0, v1)` once I got those weight variable tensors, but I don't know to how to get them safely.

One possible solution maybe using `tf.get_collection()` to get all trainable variables. But I don't know how to get only **weight** variable without **bias** variables.

Another solution is `layer.get_weights()`, but it get `numpy` arrays, although I can clip them with `numpy` APIs and set them using `layer.set_weights()`, but this may need CPU-GPU corporation, and may not be a good choice since clip operation needs to be performed on each train step.

The only way I know is access them directly using **exact** variable names which I can get from TF lower level APIs or TensorBoard, but this is may not be safe since naming rule of Keras is not guaranteed to be stable.

Is there any clean way to perform `clip_by_value` only on those `W`s with Tensorflow and Keras?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use constraints([here](https://keras.io/constraints/)) class to implement new constraints on parameters.

Here is how you can easily implement clip on weights and use it in your model.

```
from keras.constraints import Constraint
from keras import backend as K

class WeightClip(Constraint):
    '''Clips the weights incident to each hidden unit to be inside a range
    '''
    def __init__(self, c=2):
        self.c = c

    def __call__(self, p):
        return K.clip(p, -self.c, self.c)

    def get_config(self):
        return {'name': self.__class__.__name__,
                'c': self.c}

import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=100, W_constraint = WeightClip(2)))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')

X = np.random.random((1000,100))
Y = np.random.random((1000,1))

model.fit(X,Y)
```

I have tested the running of the above code, but not the validity of the constraints. You can do so by getting the model weights after training using `model.get_weights()` or `model.layers[idx].get_weights()` and checking whether its abiding the constraints.

Note: The constrain is not added to all the model weights .. but just to the weights of the specific layer its used and also `W_constraint` adds constrain to `W` param and b_constraint to `b` (bias) param

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried it on a toy problem for y=ax+b, it works perfectly!

Comment: There is problem when implementing it with Tensorflow. When using model.fit, it works perfectly, however when using sess.run(tran_step,...) with TF commands, it seems that the constrains does not work. Any ideas about how to fix it?

Comment: You are probably using optimizer object from tensorflow. keras constraints are applied in the optimizer classes implemented in Keras. For example for SGD, here are the constraints applied: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L184-L187. So you need to use keras optimizer for getting the train_step. `tran_step = model.optimizer.get_updates(model.trainable_weights, model.constraints, model.total_loss)`. Otherwise you can do is use `model.train_on_batch()` which will take care of all the keras internals & trains just on single batch just as `sess.run(tran_step,...)`

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I'll try to use the first solution. The reason I use TF with Keras API instead of Kears directly is that I'm trying to avoid using model, thus I can add some complected architecture (like GatedCNN in PixelCNN) to the network in the future. By the way, it seems that `keraslayers.W.name` can return name of weight variables. However I still can't apply clip to `Convolution2D` layers since TF report that shape of weight variable is not given explicitly.

Comment: Well good luck. If you have other doubts ask a new question. Please accept the answer if it helped.